# Can I error handle await Promise.all with a try-catch block?

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code:

```
    const [games, songs] = await Promise.all([
        getGames(),
        getSongs(),
    ]);
```

but currently errors are not handled in any way. Would it be correct to surround that piece of code with try-catch like this:

```
    try {
        const [games, songs] = await Promise.all([
            getGames(),
            getSongs(),
        ]);
    } catch (error) {
        // error handle
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way to do it. `await` turns promise rejection into an exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`try/catch` is a correct way to catch errors from `Promise.all`, but at the same time, it will ignore all fulfilled requests once only a single request failed, which is not ideal if you still want to have other successful requests' data instead of logging errors, so I'd suggest you use [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

With this solution, it will keep all requests including failed ones and successful ones

```
const [groupedMeditations, meditationPreferences] = await Promise.allSettled([
   getMeditationsByGroup(),
   getAllPreferences(),
]);
```

A possible result can be

```
[
   {status: "fulfilled", value: "successful value"}, // your 1st request passed
   {status: "rejected",  reason: "Error: an error"} //your 2nd request failed
]
```

From that response, you can filter or log errors

Just one side note that `Promise.allSettled` does not work for IE, so you need to have [polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-promise) to overcome that

Hopefully, it's helpful for your case :D

Comment: So if the first promise fails, the second one will be unsuccessful even though it hasn't failed?

Comment: All responses are classified with statuses, nothing called failed with `Promise.allSettled`, and all requests are separate (not in sequence). The successful one will have the status `fulfilled` and the failed one will have the status `rejected` @Bobimaru

Comment: So Promise.allSettled allows me to more easily handle the different statuses, but the actual functionality is the same?

Comment: yupp it is @Bobimaru